# Passing odd questions on freelance websites

Tags: freelance-websites

I see many tests on freelancing sites that are old, or questions that don't get used in a practical sense. How does one pass these question, when you're master of Adobe Photoshop, but questions are odd? For example, using only version 6.0.

Do the expert people research and see what questions are being used, and copy them to answer them? How do they determine these test questions?

Comment: They once created those tests with latest technologies and then they don't care to update them. So, only thing you can do is use google for answers, learn old technologies, leave the test or make random guesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those test can be taken a few times, each time after X days have passed. You can either memorize odd questions and find an answer on the net, or simply take screenshots of them and find the answers later.

They are mostly of general type just to show potential clients your potential qualities. If you're in 1%, it does not mean that you're a good worker.